# How do you convert time stamp that has AM/PM at the end of the string?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert this time stamp to POSIXct

```
t1 <- c("19-Jun-13 06.00.00.00 PM")
```

If I do this:

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct(t1, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

whould this convert this time stamp right? Does that considder the AM/PM at the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read `?strptime`.  `%p`, which only works with `%I`, not `%H`. Your time format is also incorrect. Your times are separated by `"."`, not `":"`.

```
as.POSIXct("19-Jun-13 06.00.00.00 PM", format="%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p")
```

Comment: that's how get the data. I need to convert this to timestamp in R. your answer did not work for me.

Comment: @user1471980: I realize you get the data with times separated by `"."`, and that's why you have to use a format with `"%I.%M.%OS"` instead of `"%I:%M:OS"`. What about my answer didn't work? It converts the string, `"19-Jun-13 06.00.00.00 PM"` to a `POSIXct` object.

Comment: I get this when I do your suggestions 2013-06-19, I need the hour and the second as well.

Comment: @user1471980: that's a timezone conversion issue. I can't help debug that without knowing your OS and R version. You can try setting the `tz="GMT"` in the `as.POSIXct` call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understad why  `strptime` doesn't recognize properly the `%p` format. However, the function `dmy_hms`from package `lubridate` works well.

`lubridate::dmy_hms("19-Jun-13 06.00.00.00 PM")` creates the following result:

`[1] "2013-06-19 18:00:00 UTC"`

which you can "reformat" if you want, say Y-m-d H:M:

`as.POSIXct(dmy_hms("19-Jun-13 06.00.00.00 PM"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
[1] "2013-06-19 18:00:00 UTC"`